# Get field accessibility for a particular profile in the Org

Tags: apex, visualforce, permissions

I am trying to get the list of invisible fields from a field accessibility point of view(not FLS) , can someone please check the issue - the code compiles, however I don't get the result in the format "objectname.field name":

**Controller**

```
public class HiddenFieldsController {

 public List<String> gethiddenFields(){
   List<String> hiddenFields=new List<String>();
        for(SObjectType sobjectType: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
        DescribeSObjectResult dsr = sobjectType.getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> fieldMap = dsr.fields.getMap();


        for (string fieldname : fieldMap.KeySet()){
           Schema.Sobjectfield field = fieldMap.get(fieldname);
           Schema.Describefieldresult dfr = field.getDescribe();
           if (dfr.isAccessible()==false){
               hiddenFields.Add(dfr.getName());
               System.Debug(dsr.getName() + dfr.getName() + '   Not Accessible:');
           }
        }

    }
 return hiddenfields;
 }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="HiddenFieldsController">
        <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageblocksection title="Hidden Fields" columns="1">
                        <apex:pageblocktable title="Hidden Fields" value="{!hiddenfields}" var="results">
                            <apex:column title="HiddenFields" value="{!results}"></apex:column>
                            </apex:pageblocktable>
                            </apex:pageblocksection>
                            </apex:pageBlock>
                            </apex:form>
                            </apex:page>
```

Comment: FYI, isAccessible is the same as "read" FLS; it has nothing to with page layout/record type visibility.